# Gridview not showing properly as a header of Listview

Tags: android, listview, android-gridview

I want to **achieve Fig-1** but I am **stuck with Fig-2** and not able to see full gridview as a header of Listview.

[image]

**As you can see the gridview is not showing fully and hiding behind Listview in Fig-2**

Gridview xml :

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:cacheColorHint="#ffffffff"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Listview xml :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment code :

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentpage_layout, null);

    listView=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listview);

    header=inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_layout,null);

    gridView=(GridView)header.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    listView.addHeaderView(header);
    gridViewAdapter=new CustomGridViewAdapter(getActivity(),images,toptexts, bottomtexts);
    listViewAdapter=new CustomListViewAdapter(getActivity(),images,toptexts,bottomtexts);

    gridView.setAdapter(gridViewAdapter);

    listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);


   return view;
}
```

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Provide the xml so we can help.

Comment: its because of you have mentioned height just minimize height and check

Comment: I have added xml files

Comment: can you show your code where you are inflating header view and adding it to list vew.

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: Try with this: ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview, listView,
                false);
  listView.addHeaderView(header, null, false);

Comment: @Developer I have tried that too, it does not works.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17629542/how-to-inflate-another-layout-inside-getview-of-gridview-adapter-in-android

Comment: Is there any problem if you use that in a single layout that is gridview and listiview ? @AshishShukla

Comment: try adding the header view after setting the adapter to gridview and before listview and also change gridview relativelayout height to wrap_content

Comment: @AshishShukla For your design either you can use layout_weight property in vertical linear layout or you can give dynamic height to list view so it will not overlap your grid content.
i haven't check this code but you can try
http://stackoverflow.com/a/19117325/2128166

Comment: @androidnoobdev the code is for listview, what about gridview ?

Comment: @AshishShukla check out this code. hope it will help. it is for layout and apply dynamic height also if this won't work.
http://pastebin.com/sPZ4Ercn

Comment: @androidnoobdev not this code, i want the code for  setGridViewHeightBasedOnChildren() for gridview

Comment: @AshishShukla why you want to set grid view height also ?
it will take space as much it require and then you give dynamic height to listview so it will fit into screen.
i hope it will work.
and we are not here to provide you full code man
do some googling...

Comment: @androidnoobdev i just want the replacement function for getDividerHeight() for GridView.

Comment: @AshishShukla Maybe my question is stupid but there's something I don't understand very well. Do you want to handle scrolling of GridView and ListView as if it is a single component (so a single scrolling) or you just need to have GridView fixed and ListView scrolling?

Comment: You are correct on your first question i.e single scrolling

Comment: @AshishShukla ok, is it mandatory for you to use GridView and ListView or is it ok to migrate to RecyclerView? With RecyclerView I think it's much easier to get outcome you need.

Comment: I was using Recyclerview but bcoz of the unanswered Marshalling  exceptions i switched to Listview

Comment: @AshishShukla uhm ok... I have a solution ready for you with RecyclerView. Of course I can share with you but I want to be sure this could be a valid solution for you. I think in any case that using GridView together with ListView could be difficult due to the fact that they both implement scrolling, so merging them could lead to weird results.

Comment: but i have seen two listview together working properly in single layout using single scrolling

Comment: @AshishShukla well, ok... I just mean that this is not the approach I would follow for implementing this scenario. RecyclerView offers proper features for handling situations like yours. But that's because I was asking if you expect an answer regardless of used components or if you want this to be implemented with GridView and ListView. BTW can I ask you the link to the question about marshalling?

Comment: there are marshalling questions for other viewgroups but not for Recyclerview thats why i switched to Listview

Comment: @AshishShukla uhm ok... I'm asking because I've implemented your scenario with RecyclerView but I'm not doing any marshalling. So I'm wondering if I'm missing something. Well... if you want to go deeper into RecyclerView solution we can even continue in chat of course. If you want to keep GridView and ListView I need more time for understanding how to effectively combining them, in particular for avoiding eventual performance issues.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102455/discussion-between-ashish-shukla-and-thetonrifles).

Comment: @AshishShukla get after calling setAdater for gridview calculate height of gridview and set as height in layout param

Comment: @Jaiprakash Soni what to replace for getDividerHeight() in Listview for Gridview while calculating divider height for gridview

Comment: @AshishShukla did you checked code I shared with you in chat?

Comment: Actually you don't need to calculate the size manually you can do it by override the onmeasure method of grid view . Please check the link for more information . http://stackoverflow.com/a/22727503/3257178

Comment: @Ashish Shukla Have yoy find solution for this I am having same issue please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey Guys I got my Answer using Gridview as a Header of Listview.

I just **Calculated the Divider Height for Gridview** using below method and it worked perfectly as I wanted.

```
   public static void setDynamicHeightGridView(GridView mListView,String oddeven) {
        ListAdapter mListAdapter = mListView.getAdapter();
        if (mListAdapter == null) {
            return;
        }
        int height = 0;
        int desiredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(mListView.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);


        for(int i = 0; i < mListAdapter.getCount(); i++){
            View listItem = mListAdapter.getView(i, null, mListView);
            listItem.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            height += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
            itemHeight=listItem.getMeasuredHeight()/3;
        }

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = mListView.getLayoutParams();

        if(oddeven.equals("odd")){
            if(mListAdapter.getCount()>=5){
                int count=((mListAdapter.getCount()-5)/2) + 1;
                params.height = ((height - (height / 3)) - (itemHeight * count)) + 20 + (count * 5);

            }else{
                params.height = height - (height / 3) + 20;
            }

        }else if(oddeven.equals("even")) {
            params.height = height/2 + 20;
        }


        mListView.setLayoutParams(params);
        mListView.requestLayout();
    }
```

**Edited :**

Finally the **Exact** Answer :

**For Even number of views set :**

```
params.height = height/2 + 20;
```

**For Odd number of Views set :**

```
params.height = ((height - (height / 3)) - (itemHeight * count)) + 20 + (count * 5);
```

where :

- *I have used 5 as the number for comparision 
  bcoz after this value of Adapters Count the variation in the space between 
  gridview and listview is increasing with fixed values.*
- *For the space before 5 is handled in the else part.*
- *itemHeight is the incremental value with which the space is increasing*
- *20 is the margin space between gridview and listview*
- *(count x 5) is the value for managing the margin as the elements increases.*

bcoz it was giving me *double the space for Gridview height* above Listview for Even number of views

and *Gridview + half it's height space* for Odd number of views

Hope It Helps :)

Comment: You will have to set height just like you did as a gridview is scrollable and even the listview is scrollable. So in future whenever we try to put a scrollable view inside a listview or any other scrollable view, we need to set the height of the inner view irrespective of the orientation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way , **Taking your Grid and List in single layout** and using `android:weightSum` to differentiate so that it will be applicable in all devices ,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:cacheColorHint="#ffffffff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

**Fragment code :**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentpage_layout, null);

    listView=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listview);
    gridView=(GridView)header.findViewById(R.id.gridview);

    //your code

    gridView.setAdapter(gridViewAdapter);
    listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);


   return view;
```

### }

### OR

If you want the whole gridview to be displayed fully first and below it should be the listview and when you scroll the gridview should go upwards and the listview should follow it behind as in Fig-1

Checkout this [Awesome-MaterialDesign](https://github.com/lightSky/Awesome-MaterialDesign) library with simple explaination.As shown in below figure

[image]

Comment: I have tried that too it's not working.If your code is working please post full code

Comment: what is not working in your side ? where you have stuck ? @AshishShukla

Comment: Thanx for the library link but i want to do it without that.

Comment: As you can see in the Fig-2 above the gridview is hiding behind the listview

Comment: you are welcome. tell me where you stuck in your code using gird and list in single layout @AshishShukla

Comment: Try as i have described in my answer using weightSum  so it will not happen @AshishShukla

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102338/discussion-between-ashish-shukla-and-amit-vaghela).

Comment: where have you stuck ?@AshishShukla

Answer (score 0):

When you want to inflate your **GridLayout** also reference your listView With something like this :

```
header = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.your_header, mListView, false);
```

And one more things : pass your relativeLayout instead of your GrideLayout as header.

Answer (score 0):

try adding `android:layout_marginTop="some_value"` in the `RelativeLayout` of the `ListView`